# Clipping tool giving incorrect shape?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip

I am trying to clip a shapefile of the Midwest using a Great Lakes shapefile so that it matches my political areas boundary. Whenever I use the Clip tool, it outputs the lakes clipped to states, whereas I need the states clipped to lakes. No matter which input and output I use, it gives the same result.

Comment: Do you think you could add a picture with a description?

Comment: What version and license level of ArcGIS? I think you may be using the wrong tool for what you want to do - if states overlaps lakes, and you want to cut the lakes out of the states, you could use Erase (but that requires an Advanced license). You may want to look at the [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) and [Overlay Tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Overlay_toolset/000800000009000000/) help files to get a better idea of how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the [Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000) tool will give you what you need. Erase the lakes shapefile from the states shapefile.